# Ultraslow upload speed when nating with iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

I'm configuring a network and I need to allow access only for certain MAC addresses.

Let eth0 and eth1 are physical interfaces. eth1 is connected to the external network and eth0 and its vlans are in the internal network.

For that purpouse, I'm using Linux iptables, and I have the following code for default configuration.

```sh
# Allowing ip forwarding and loopback

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Setting up nat and default chains settings

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -N FILTER
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Setting up default configuration

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -i eth0+ -o eth1 -j FILTER
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m conntrack \
--ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT,SNAT,INVALID -i eth0+ -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD ! -p tcp -i eth0+ -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0+ -m state \
--state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

By doing that, I'm filtering all incoming tcp traffic with state NEW and allowing all traffic of any other protocol or tcp with other statuses. I'm handling those filtered tcp requests with the following rule

```sh
# Allowing tcp traffic with ctstate NEW for certain mac

iptables -A FILTER -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -i eth0+ -o eth1 \ 
-m mac --mac-source <mac> -j ACCEPT
```

On a test ambient, with this configuration, allowed MAC's can access internet with normal download speed, but upload speed is nearly zero. Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to troubleshoot issues like this is to capture the traffic and analyze it with the `wireshark`.

In most cases problems with speed are caused by MTU issues. MTU issues can be caused by blocking of the `ICMP` packets required by the `Path MTU discovery`.

Paste the full firewall rule set. Use `iptables-save -c` command to list all rules, not only from the `filter` table.

Check the rule counters. Remember the order of firewall rules is very important.

Comment: The problem was caused by MTU. It was necessary to set mtu 8972 in interfaces file. Thanks for your help :)